# Development setup advice needed - Django + Apache2 + mod_wsgi - on Mac and Ubuntu Dev Server

Tags: django, apache, apache2, mod-wsgi

I need advice if this setup is ok. I have a personal dev server which runs Ubuntu. I have setup Ubuntu completely with git, django, mod_wsgi and apache2 running. I will be developing using my Macbook Pro.

My idea was to have identical directory structure on both machines off of web root.

Say:

```
Mac: /path/to/webroot/
                      ...project1/
                      ...project2/

Ubu: /home/me/webroot/
                      ...project1/
                      ...project2/
```

And use git to initiate the repo on Ubu server and clone it on my mac and start developing. This way I will achieve:

1. Multiple code instances. So that if Ubuntu crashes, I have the code on Mac
2. I will have the code locally on my Mac and that will help if I am on the move.

Please advice if this is a good thinking or needs any improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds OK to me.

> Multiple code instances. So that if Ubuntu crashes, I have the code on Mac

If you want to be extra paranoid (like I am) you should think of a third place where your code  is available. A git solution like [github](http://github.com/) plus something like [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) might be worth pondering.

Comment: Go with github (for git), bitbucket (Mercurial) or beanstalk (svn). Dropbox is awesome, but wasn't built for source code version control

Comment: @stevejalim: I use both github and Dropbox. All my static, non version controlled assets as well as (temporarily) shared project documents go into a Dropbox folder.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question: Is it a good idea that my macbook pro should also have a setup of apache+mod_wsgi+django that enables me to run the same code on my macbook? If yes, then do I need to install a fresh copy of Apache on Macbook or is it ok to have something like XAMPP+mod_wsgi?

Comment: I think it should and XAMPP should be fine. I'd just have to install my mod_wsgi with XAMPPs Apache. Sweet!

Answer (score 1):

If your using Django, why bother installing Apache. Django comes with an
excellent dev environment. I just use: `manage.py runserver`

You achieve your 2 points, by just having git clones on the server and on your
laptop for work. No need for Apache.

Two notes:

1. Since I ran into a bug that occurred on MySQL, but didn't on sqlite, I test
   projects on the same dbbackend before deploying. But for development on the
   laptop, all I need is Python, Django and sqlite.
2. I try to use the same Python as on the deployment server. I've deployed on
   "Enterprise" distro's which means ancient ("stable") versions, that miss new
   features. [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) helps keeping things seperated.

These two can be solved by just adding an extra 'test' deployment of your
project on the server for a last testrun on the same platform just before your
updates.

PS: If you don't mind installing and configuring the extra software why not go all out and install an Ubuntu VM in a [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). You could even make your main server a VM and every now and then take a snapshot of the image on the road...

**edit:** runserver will listen on port 8000 on localhost. If you want to connect to it from other hosts use `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` to listen on 8000 on all ip-addresser or, if you're worried on leaking info to snoopers, use `ssh -L8000:127.0.0.1:8000 <ubuntu-server>` to tunnel 8000 on localhost (your client) to 8000 on localhost (your server) through ssh. Whichever fits your needs.

Comment: `manage.py runserver` I tried this command on Ubuntu server I have but I could not access the python's dev server by <ubuntu ip address>:8000 for some reason. if port is different, there should not be any conflict. Hence, I decided to go to Apache.

Comment: I like the virtualEnv idea. Although, I do not want Virtual Machines running on my Macbook. I do have VMWare but I hardly use it. I feel that it speeds up the death of my hard drive. lol

Comment: Virtualenv is not just great for mimicking deployment environment on your dev-machine, it can help when you might have different projects that use different versions of apps and have different module dependencies.